# How to use cumulative distribution functions within an interactive simulator

Tags: exponential-distribution, python, simulation, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am building a simple simulator in `python` that should simulate an event taking place based on its `cumulative distributed function` (`CDF`).

A pseudo-code (in `python`) for it is shown below for illustration purposes.

```
import math
import random

x = 0
event_rate = 0.01

for t in range(1000):
  cfd = 1 - math.exp(-x*event_rate)  # Calculates the cumulative distribution at point `t`
  seed = random.random()
  if seed > cfd:
    x += 1   # Increase event counter.
    continue # Event didn't trigger yet.
  else:
    x = 0    # Reset event counter once the event happens.
```

To me, the code above seems to be correctly calculating the exponential distribution based on the formula below:

$$CFD=1-e^{-t*\lambda}$$

For an `event_rate` ($\lambda$) of 0.01, I would expect the event to happen once around 100 time steps in average. However, the event happens way more frequently.

I also found out during debugging that the event is being triggered frequently when the probability of the event happening is still too low (is this due to the nature of the `random.random()` function?). I would expect the event to be triggered more often when the probability of it happening (its `CFD`) is higher.

I think what I am doing wrong is the `seed` calculation which I am using to trigger the probabilistic event.

Also, at any time `t` on the simulation, I believe I am calculating the correct probability of the event happening. But I think I am not "triggering" it correctly in the simulation by just simply comparing the `CFD` against a random number.

What should I do instead?

Comment: I changed things a bit and instead of a simple `random.random()` function, I am using a Gaussian distribution function like this: `seed = random.gauss(0,0.25)`. The frequency of the event now is matching better what I would expect. However, I am not sure if this is coincidence or if this approach is correct.